# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12. Required by:

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I updated Android Studio and I am now getting this error. I also noticed I started getting these IDE Fatal errors:

**JDOMParse Exception: Error on line 18: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".: Error on line 18: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".**

I have the latest code releases:

Studio 0.8.4

SDK Tools 23.0.2

SDK Platform Tools 20

SDK Build-tools 20

SDK Platform Android L Preview

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
**// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}**
```

And:

```
**apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion L
        targetSdkVersion L
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}**
```

I have tried taking the plus off of of this:  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'  as suggested by some and it still does not work.

Comment: Hmm. The only differences I see with the grade files I have is that `compileSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are all integers, 20 in my case. This corresponds to the L SDK, so maybe you could try changing these to integer values (no '') of 20.

Comment: @PaulRatazzi I tried your suggestion and I get the same error as before.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was nothing other than my proxy server not allowing certain files through.  Apparently Android Studio pulls Gradle down from the Internet rather than coming packaged with it and then builds it's wrapper.  If certain file types are not allowed through it will partially build and can give these odd and misleading errors.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if I don't use simple quote for `L`, I have an error (but not this one). Can you set your gradle file like this ? (I'm not sure the problem is here)

```
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 'L'
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: So I tried your suggestion and I get the same two errors as before.  The **JDOMParseException** and **Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:012**. I have the files too in my path; so I don't see why it can not find them.